# Trying to integrate Paypal Payment Pro api, receiving error 10002

Tags: php, paypal

New to Paypal Payment Pro and not using an off-the-shelf shopping cart.  I have my account set up and would like to use one of PayPal's hosted checkout pages.  For testing purposes I have just generated a Buy It Now button with a $1.00 charge which takes me to the Paypal Checkout page.  However, when the attempt to process the payment is made, I am receiving the following in my error log, which is where I have sent the return array:

```
[06-Jul-2015 11:22:57 America/Halifax] Array
(
[TYPE] => S
[RESPMSG] => Invalid merchant information: 10002-You do not have permissions to make this API call
[ACCT] => 1111
[COUNTRY] => CA
[TAX] => 0.00
[CARDTYPE] => 0
[LASTNAME] => NotProvided
[PNREF] => B70P7DC0A255
[TENDER] => CC
[AVSDATA] => XXN
[METHOD] => CC
[SECURETOKEN] => 9f50xjlryKE2myw4aDnjM3wsJ
[SHIPTOCOUNTRY] => CA
[AMT] => 1.00
[SECURETOKENID] => 559a8f2cdb4034.19928099
[TRANSTIME] => 2015-07-06 07:22:55
[HOSTCODE] => 10002
[COUNTRYTOSHIP] => CA
[RESULT] => 5
[BILLTOCOUNTRY] => CA
[EXPDATE] => 0620
[TRXTYPE] => S
)
```

It is the RESPMSG of Invalid merchant information: 10002-You do not have permissions to make this API call which has me frustrated.  I can't see why it's not working.  I've been getting the run-around from PayPal so far and have yet to be able to speak with anyone who knows how to help.

Here is my code...

```
function makeBuyButton($amt, $txt = "Buy Now!")
{
$PF_USER = "apiusername";
$PF_VENDOR = "merchantname";
$PF_PARTNER = "paypalca";
$PF_PWD = "xxxxxxxx"; // <--modified for forum
$PF_MODE = "TEST";
$PF_HOST_ADDR = "https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com";
//  $PF_HOST_ADDR = "https://payflowpro.paypal.com;

$secureTokenID = uniqid('', true);
$postData = "USER=" . $PF_USER
        .   "&VENDOR=" . $PF_VENDOR
        .   "&PARTNER=" . $PF_PARTNER
        .   "&PWD=" . $PF_PWD
        .   "&CREATESECURETOKEN=Y"
        .   "&SECURETOKENID=" . $secureTokenID
        .   "&TRXTYPE=S"
        .   "&AMT=" . $amt;

//initialize and setup request

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $PF_HOST_ADDR);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);

//ready the postData to send
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

//send the data to PayPal and assign the response
$resp = curl_exec($ch);

//Confirm that a response was received and handle the error
if(!$resp)
{
    return "<p>To order, please contact us</p>";
}

//Parse and assign to array
parse_str($resp, $arr);

if($arr['RESULT'] != 0)
{
    return "<p>To order, please contact us</p>";
}

return "<form method='post' action='https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com/'>
<input type='hidden' name='SECURETOKEN' value='" . $arr['SECURETOKEN'] . "' />
<input type='hidden' name='SECURETOKENID' value='" . $secureTokenID . "' />
<input type='hidden' name='MODE' value='" . $PF_MODE . "' />
<input type='submit' value='" . $txt . "' />
</form>";
}
```

I call the function with

```
<?=makeBuyButton(1.00); ?>
```

The button works, I get to the checkout page, but unfortantely it doesn't process and gives the 10002 error above.

Thanks for any help given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a problem on PayPal's end.  They had to tweak my account a bit, toggle this, reset that, wait an hour for their database to update then bam!  In 23 easy steps, the problem was solved!

Bottom line, the answer is that in this case, if you have followed all the suggestions for this error code and it still hasn't worked for your, give PayPal a call.  They can see what is going on from their end and sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the error 10002 for Paypal Pro Integration, follow the steps below.

```
1. Go to Settings › Store Setup › Payments, and click the PayPal Standard Payments tab.

2. Remove your credentials, then re-enter them. If you copied and pasted the data, make sure there are no spaces before or after the information. We recommend first pasting them into a text editing program such as Notepad or TextEdit to ensure this.

3. Make sure that you are not in test mode either on this page or within your PayPal account.
```

Comment: Where do I go to do this?  I'm looking through manager.paypal.com and paypal.com and can't find the settings.